# Updating rows of dataframe with other dataframe column vlaue for each group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two dataframe(df1, df2) with different size .
The df2 is subset of df1.

Date columns are formatted as date (y.m.d).
(Location and location_id have a one to one mapping.)

tl;dr my goal is to use df2’s date to filter any date that comes after that for its specific location.
df1

| date | location | location_id | y | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.02.02 | A | 1 | 26 | 78 |
| 22.02.02 | B | 2 | 45 | 67 |
| 22.02.02 | C | 3 | 46 | 57 |
| 22.02.02 | D | 4 | 27 | 89 |
| 22.02.01 | A | 1 | 37 | 67 |
| 22.02.01 | B | 2 | 82 | 23 |
| 22.02.01 | C | 3 | 56 | 68 |
| 22.02.01 | D | 4 | 67 | 90 |
| 22.01.31 | A | 1 | 61 | 37 |
| 22.01.31 | B | 2 | 90 | 65 |
| 22.01.31 | C | 3 | 43 | 34 |
| 22.01.31 | D | 4 | 12 | 23 |
| 22.01.30 | A | 1 | 38 | 48 |
| 22.01.30 | B | 2 | 57 | 53 |
| 22.01.30 | C | 3 | 75 | 95 |
| 22.01.30 | D | 4 | 76 | 19 |

df2

| date | location | location_id | y | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.02.01 | A | 1 | 37 | 67 |
| 22.02.02 | B | 2 | 45 | 67 |
| 22.01.30 | C | 3 | 75 | 95 |
| 22.01.31 | D | 4 | 12 | 23 |

In df2 each location corresponds to one and only one date. I want to use this location to date map from df2, and apply a function to df1. This function should set x and y columns to zero (or na) for any date that comes after specified date for that location on df2.

So the output df3 would be like this:

df3

| date | location | location_id | y | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.02.02 | A | 1 |  |  |
| 22.02.02 | B | 2 | 45 | 67 |
| 22.02.02 | C | 3 |  |  |
| 22.02.02 | D | 4 |  |  |
| 22.02.01 | A | 1 | 37 | 67 |
| 22.02.01 | B | 2 | 82 | 23 |
| 22.02.01 | C | 3 |  |  |
| 22.02.01 | D | 4 |  |  |
| 22.01.31 | A | 1 | 61 | 37 |
| 22.01.31 | B | 2 | 90 | 65 |
| 22.01.31 | C | 3 |  |  |
| 22.01.31 | D | 4 | 12 | 23 |
| 22.01.30 | A | 1 | 38 | 48 |
| 22.01.30 | B | 2 | 57 | 53 |
| 22.01.30 | C | 3 | 75 | 95 |
| 22.01.30 | D | 4 | 76 | 19 |

I do not know how to solve this kind of questions, what is the most efficient way to solve this, is it using dplyr or for loop?!
I am approaching this with using dplyr ,groupby and mutate. Something Like this (I do not get result that I want).

Here my code which does not give me the result:

```
df1 %>%

group_by(location, id_location) %>%

mutate(date =  df2$date, y= df2$y, x = df2$x)
```

I am new to R and using dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. First, I make a version of `df2` with the dates stored as dates, which'll make it simpler to use them for calculations, and call that `date_limits`. (It's not strictly necessary here since your date strings' alphabetical sorting will also be chronological, but I think it's good practice.) I don't need the `x`/`y` values since they're in df1 already.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
date_limits <- df2 %>%
  mutate(max_date = ymd(date)) %>%
  select(max_date, location, location_id)
```

Then we can join those dates onto `df1` using `dplyr::left_join`, sort of like `vlookup` in excel, or `merge` in base R. It will by default use all the common variables (in this case `location` and `location_id`) to bring in the `max_date` for that location.

Then I change `y` and `x` using `mutate(across(...` so that if the `max_date` we pulled in is later than the date, change it to `NA`, otherwise leave it as is.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  left_join(date_limits) %>%
  mutate(across(y:x, ~if_else(date > max_date, NA_integer_, .)))
```

Result

```
Joining, by = c("location", "location_id")
         date location location_id  y  x   max_date
1  2022-02-02        A           1 NA NA 2022-02-01
2  2022-02-02        B           2 45 67 2022-02-02
3  2022-02-02        C           3 NA NA 2022-01-30
4  2022-02-02        D           4 NA NA 2022-01-31
5  2022-02-01        A           1 37 67 2022-02-01
6  2022-02-01        B           2 82 23 2022-02-02
7  2022-02-01        C           3 NA NA 2022-01-30
8  2022-02-01        D           4 NA NA 2022-01-31
9  2022-01-31        A           1 61 37 2022-02-01
10 2022-01-31        B           2 90 65 2022-02-02
11 2022-01-31        C           3 NA NA 2022-01-30
12 2022-01-31        D           4 12 23 2022-01-31
13 2022-01-30        A           1 38 48 2022-02-01
14 2022-01-30        B           2 57 53 2022-02-02
15 2022-01-30        C           3 75 95 2022-01-30
16 2022-01-30        D           4 76 19 2022-01-31
```

Comment: Thank you, I never taught about using left join. This solution is way much simpler than I thought!